# While Loop only returns one row from 9000+ records

Tags: php, mysqli, datatables

I had a script for this that worked great in PHP 5.3. New host only supports 5.5 so I've done some modifying. So far, I can only get one row to be returned. I've been agonising for hours and I just can't see why.

Is this possibly because I'm not using array_push() after the while loop? In my original script I had it but found out with this one I got a 500 Internal Server Error with it which disappeared if I took it out.

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$row_array = array();

$query = "SELECT title,year,author,journal,keywords,abstract,url FROM entries";

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {

/* fetch object array */
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];
        $row_array['year'] = $row['year'];
        $row_array['author'] = $row['author'];
        $row_array['journal'] = $row['journal'];
        $row_array['keywords'] = $row['keywords'];
        $row_array['abstract'] = $row['abstract'];
        $row_array['url'] = $row['url'];

    }

    echo '{"data":';
    echo json_encode($row_array);
    echo '}';

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

What get's returned is this:

> {"data":{"title":"ERGOT The Genus Claviceps","year":"1999","author":null,"journal":null,"keywords":"LSD","abstract":null,"url":null}}

Which is fine and dandy and all except there are about 9500 other rows that should be coming back with it.

Comment: Aren't you constantly over-writing the entries in `$row_array` on each iteration?

Comment: Yeah, It appears so. This is my first time messing with 5.5. I don't know why it didn't do that in 5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop keeps overwriting the same array elements in the $row_array array.

To do what you're trying to do:
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row_array[] = $row;
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
$row_array= array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp['title'] = $row['title'];
        $tmp['year'] = $row['year'];
        $tmp['author'] = $row['author'];
        $tmp['journal'] = $row['journal'];
        $tmp['keywords'] = $row['keywords'];
        $tmp['abstract'] = $row['abstract'];
        $tmp['url'] = $row['url'];
        $row_array[] = $tmp;
    }
echo '{"data":';
    echo json_encode($row_array);
    echo '}';
```

Comment: just do it like that , u loop results was covered. so i create a temporary array to store it ,  and push to "$row_array" ,every time.

Comment: This just returns a very long JSON array of 'tmp' over and over again.

Comment: try it like that :   echo json_encode( array("data" => $row_array) );

Comment: This is what's returned:

{"data":["tmp","tmp",...............................and so on and so forth

Comment: I sorry , i try it on my database, i forget to add a "$" on  the line of " $row_array[] = $tmp ", now,  i have get the right returned:   {"data":[{"title":"aa","year":"aa","author":"a","journal":"a","keywords":"a","abstract":"a","url":"a"}} .  so would u mind to try again?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a multi-dimensional array and you have taken a single dimensional array.

So, every time record comes, it overwrites older one.

Hence, you are getting the last record only.

Modify your code to:

```
$i=0;
$row_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $row_array[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
  $row_array[$i]['year'] = $row['year'];
  $row_array[$i]['author'] = $row['author'];
  $row_array[$i]['journal'] = $row['journal'];
  $row_array[$i]['keywords'] = $row['keywords'];
  $row_array[$i]['abstract'] = $row['abstract'];
  $row_array[$i]['url'] = $row['url'];
  ++$i;
}
```

Comment: Returned a 500 Internal Server Error when doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

Your `$row_array` replaces every time and you get the last one. change your code to:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row_array[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
    $row_array[$i]['year'] = $row['year'];
    $row_array[$i]['author'] = $row['author'];
    $row_array[$i]['journal'] = $row['journal'];
    $row_array[$i]['keywords'] = $row['keywords'];
    $row_array[$i]['abstract'] = $row['abstract'];
    $row_array[$i]['url'] = $row['url'];
    $i++;
}

echo '{"data":';
    echo json_encode($row_array);
    echo '}';
```

Comment: Returned a 500 Internal Server Error when doing it this way